# Modify error pages templates for Keycloak theme

Tags: templates, keycloak, response.redirect, http-error

Is there any possibility to change the way how Keycloak displays pages for bad responses(404, 500)?
Maybe redirection or changing template for these pages?
[Simple view of 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juO7P.png)

Comment: Hey, have you solved it?

Comment: unfortunately, no :c

Comment: ahah yeah me neither i think, don't remember xd

Answer (score 1):

See this link,
https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-June/014439.html

*"... As long as the URL of the error page includes the realm it will use the login theme for that realm. Otherwise it will fallback to the login theme of the master realm. ..."*

Comment: Yes, thats what I supposed it would do, but it doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can use custom themes and templates for all kind of interfaces (Web UI, e-mails, error pages etc). You can also extend existing themes and partially override it. Please refer to the themes development guide [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes).

Comment: I appreciate your reply :) But there is nothing about pages for 404 response. I already knew about the template for errors, but modifying that errors' template means only change in template for errors in form. I need to customize the interface for the whole page when it's nothing to show (like I demonstrated on the screenshot above)

Comment: Downvoted the answer because you are providing wrong information, keycloak references itself never mention error pages.